# Search array for matching result and cout struct members C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

Finishing up an academic performance tracking program that was required as a final project last semester. I didn't finish it before it was due, and I'm trying to understand why some functions are not operating as I'd like them to.

The function (searchCourse), is intended to search an array within a struct. If a match is found, all struct members should be printed to the user. I'm searching by course alpha designator(i.e. CIT). I've loaded a file with three CIT classes into the program, and when calling this function, they're not recognized. Course alpha designator is of char data type. Would this be easier to accomplish if it were string type and using strcmp within the 'for' loop?

```
//Prompts user to enter course alpha designator for comparison purposes. 
void searchCourse(courses course[])
{
    char desig[3];//User inputs course alpha designator to compare within loop
    //Assigned array value of 4 since strcmp requires 'desig' to have a size for comparison to course[i]
    int i;//Location / loop counter

    cout << endl << "Enter course Alpha-Designator (Ex: CIT, DFIA, etc.): " << endl;//User prompt
    cin >> desig;
    //Set course info headings
    cout << endl;
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Course" << left << setw(25) << "Title" << setw(7) << "Hours" << "Grade" << endl << endl;

    //begin for loop
    for (i = 0; i < courseArrayLength; i++)
    {
       if(course[i].courseName == desig) //If the value in course.courseName is equal to user 'desig'
                                               //Have to use strcmp function when comparing c-strings in array.
                                               //I tried to use the example in CH.8-2 and apply it here. 
        {
            cout << left << setw(4) << course[i].courseName << left << setw(6) << course[i].courseNum;//Print info formatting
            cout << left << setw(25) << course[i].courseTitle << left << setw(7) << course[i].courseHours << course[i].courseGrade << endl;
        }   
        else
        {
            cout << "No courses by that designator.";//Message to display if input 'desig' finds no matches.
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Full program code is on github if anyone would like it. Any help is appreciated. This is the last two of nine functions to complete this project. If I can get a bead on how to properly fix this one, the next is essentially the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `char desig[3];` is too short for both `CIT` and `DFIA` (whatever those mean). Why don't you use `std::string`? Also, for `char[]` operator `==` is never going to return `true`, unless you are comparing with exactly the same array (not one with same contents, same address in memory).

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Does the argument for `searchCourse()` *have* to be a C-style array? Is it not allowed to be a `std::vector`? Where does `courseArrayLength` come from? It's not an input to your function.

Comment: try to minimize example and look at link @eerorika posted above

Comment: If `courseName` in `if(course[i].courseName == desig)` is `char *` and not `std::string`, you cannot compare equality with `==`, that will result in *unspecified behavior* -- for which you should be getting a warning. You can use `if (strcmp (course[i].courseName, desig) == 0)` if you cannot use `std::string`. Include `<cstring>` for `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

- `desig` is not large enough: it **must accommodate the null terminator, too**. If allowed, use `std::string`. If not, choose a large enough array, say `char desig[ 1024 ]` .
- Declare the counter variable `i` **in the `for` statement**: `for ( int i = 0;…`
- `course[ i ].courseName == desig` **compares two pointers**, not two strings. Use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp): `if ( 0 == strcmp( course[ i ].courseName, desig ) )...`. If you switch to `std::string`, you can use the comparison as you did.
- You **break the loop too soon**: when you find the first non-matching course (you may find it later). You probably want to break the loop once you find the first match: remove the `else` and move the break inside `if`.

*Welcome to SO and good luck!*

Comment: Only nit is a caution to the OP if they are on an embedded system the `desig[ 1024 ]` may be too big for the system (on normal desktops then `1024/2048` is fine). A number of colleges are now using microcontrollers for teaching (like the TI MSP432, etc....) Otherwise, nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the responses. I'm obviously new to programming, and this project taught me a lot. All of the answers gave me things to think about, and I eventually accomplished what I set out to do on my own. Anyway, the code below works.

```
void searchCourse(courses course[])
{
    string desig;//User inputs course alpha designator to compare within loop
    //Assigned array value of 4 since strcmp requires 'desig' to have a size for comparison to course[i]
    bool found = false;

    cout << endl << "Enter course Alpha-Designator (Ex: CIT, DFIA, etc.): " << endl;//User prompt
    cin >> desig;
    cout << endl;//Terminal formatting
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Course" << left << setw(25) << "Title" << setw(7) << "Hours" << "Grade" << endl << endl;
    //Format info header
    //begin for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArrayLength; i++)//For loop to process array
    {
        while (i < courseArrayLength)//While array processes...
        {
            if(strcmp(course[i].courseName, desig.c_str()) == 0) //If the value in course.courseName is equal to user 'desig'
                {
                    found = true;//Boolean 'found' is set to true
                    cout << left << setw(4) << course[i].courseName << left << setw(6) << course[i].courseNum;//Print info formatting
                    cout << left << setw(25) << course[i].courseTitle << left << setw(7); 
                    cout << course[i].courseHours << course[i].courseGrade << endl;
                    break;//Required since nested in while loop
                }   

            else if(i < courseArrayLength)//Continue array process.
                {
                    i++;                   
                }
        }
        if(found == false)//If no courses found by user defined designator...
        {
            cout << "No courses by that designator." << endl;//Message to display if input 'desig' finds no matches.
            break;
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: program is as _complete_ as I can make it since the new semester started, but if anyone is interested it's here: [link](https://github.com/cayton10/academic_tracker)